# Remove everything up to but not including pattern

Tags: sed

I am doing this and it deletes everything including the pattern. I would like it to not delete the pattern.

```
sed -i '' 's/.*Pattern//g' file
```

I would like it to do this

```
Hello this is a Pattern
Pattern
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The typical solution is

```
sed -i '' 's/.*\(Pattern\)/\1/' file
#--------------^^-------^^-^^
```

where the `\(..\)` pair is a capture group, and the `\1` indicates "replace with what was found in capture group (1)".  You can have up to 9 capture groups (maye more in ultra-modern seds).

Note, you can also do the lazymans approach and replace the complete match with your target Pattern, i.e.

```
sed -i '' 's/.*Pattern/Pattern/' file
```

**edit**  And thanks to @Beta, removed the redundant `g` from `s/../../g`.

IHTH

Comment: What is the purpose of the `g`? It seems redundant.